# postgresql update, set highest value

Tags: postgresql, update

I would like to update column 4 and set the highest value (bigint) in comparison of column 1-3.

eg. col 1, 2; col 2, 7; col 3, 4. The code should write the value of col 2 in column 4
My approach:

```
update tablename
set col 4 = max(col 1, col 2 ,col 3)
```

I get the error message, that the function max(bigint,bigint,bigint) is not existing.
I found a solution using *case when* but I wonder if there is and straight forward easy solution possible.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: yes, that happens accidently. Soory for this inconvinience. To fill out the form I have to give the url-adress of my second account, but I have no idea what it is?

Comment: It’s https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/203608/user203608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [greatest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

> The GREATEST and LEAST functions select the largest or smallest value
> from a list of any number of expressions

```
update tablename
set "col 4" = greatest("col 1","col 2" ,"col 3")
```